# Create String binary terminator

Tags: java, string

I need to place terminator to my string. Terminator might be byte 11 (or 0x0B) or possible any other in future. What is the best way to add byte to my string?

I would like to do something like:

```
String s = "122456"+char(11);
```

Comment: Why do you need to place a terminator to the string? This feels like [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What is the need for a terminator in java `String` ?

Comment: I need to send this string to com port. And protocol requires specific terminator (and field separators).

Comment: Can you show us your code - what have you tried?

Comment: Strings in Java are encoded internally as UTF-16. There's no single byte in UTF-16, all characters are 2-byte wide. How do you encode your string in your protocol?

Comment: I have updated question with sample I need to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you should use a constant for this. Try

```
public final static char TERMINATOR = 0x0B;
```

You can then use it like this in the code:

```
"122456" + TERMINATOR
```

This makes the code readable and it also makes it simple to replace the terminator with a different symbol (not in your case but generally) or to find all places where the symbol is being used.

If you need the terminator to be variable, use a field and accessor methods:

```
private char terminator = 0x0b;
public void setTerminator( char terminator ) { this.terminator = terminator; }
public char getTerminator() { return terminator; }
```

This allows you to change the terminator.

I also suggest to create a single Java type per message you plan to send. The type should know how to create the byte array that you can then transmit with an "IO service". So create accessor methods for each part of the message and then a single `encode()` method:

```
public byte[] encode() {
     String message = data1 + terminator + data2 + terminator + ...

     return message.getBytes("ISO-88591-1");
}
```

That way, you can build the message step by step and then convert it into a byte stream to send once its complete.

Comment: But I need to have terminator like variable

Comment: Then make it a property (= field) of the class and add a getter+setter.  You could use `"122456" + (char)0x0b` or "122456\u000b" but that will make it very hard to replace this with a different character in the future.

Comment: @user1501700 No you don't. You are using a fixed protocol and the protocol has fixed terminators. Otherwise it isn't a protocol.